# Filtering the record in crystal report based on dropdown value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to the crystal report,I have created a simple crystal report for filtering the record.I have created a parameter Age for filtering data based on age of a person using a dropdownlist. I get correct filtered output in the preview(eg. Age>=10).when i run the code in the browser i get the same output as in preview even if i change the condition(eg.Age>=12) my result still contains the age of persons of 10,11. I have written the below code in button click event.

```
cn.Open();
string query = "select AMST_Name,AMST_Dob,AMST_Age,AMST_Father_Name,AMST_Email_Id from Adm_M_Student where AMST_Age >= '" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "'";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable ds = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(ds);
 rdc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"));
 rdc.SetParameterValue("Age", ddl1.SelectedValue);
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdc;
 CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
 cn.Close();
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and check the value of `ddl1.SelectedValue`

Comment: thank u for the suggestion.. i even tried by adding a breakpoint, i get the correct value selected but output remains the same

Comment: After a long wait finally i found the answer for this..when we drag and drop the crystal report in the aspx page we should not bind the datasource to the crystal report. Just drag and drop with data source as none. The code written above is correct and It worked for me..